# svg fill color covering text color

Tags: svg

I'm trying to style my SVG sticker on my page. I'd like the background to be red with white text on top. I'm able to get the fill color red, but when I change the "fill" for the text, it changes but is covered by the "fill" for the background.

```
.sale-sticker.hide-for-small-only
                    a(href="")
                        svg(version='1.1', xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', xmlns:a='http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/', x='0px', y='0px', width='100%', height='100%', viewbox='0 0 157.5 157.5', style='enable-background:new 0 0 157.5 157.5;', xml:space='preserve')
                            style(type='text/css').
                                .st1 {
                                    fill: #FF3A1E;
                                    stroke: #FF3A1E;
                                    stroke-width: 2;
                                    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                                }

                                .sale-copy {
                                    font-size: 20px;
                                    font-weight: 600;

                                }

                                .sale-price-svg {
                                    font-size: 20px;
                                    font-weight: 600;
                                    color: #fff;
                                }

                                .sale-price-9 {
                                    font-size: 55px;
                                    font-weight: 700;

                                }
                            defs
                            text(x="50%", y="50%", fill="#FFFFFF")
                                if (/^(en-gb|fr)$/.test(prefLocale))
                                    if locale == "fr"
                                        tspan(class="sale-copy", x="30%", y="40%") !{ __("homepage.sale_sticker_svg")}
                                    else
                                        tspan(class="sale-copy", x="35%", y="40%") !{ __("homepage.sale_sticker_svg")}
                                    tspan(class="sale-price-svg", x="25%", y="60%") £
                                    tspan(y="75%", class="sale-price-9") 9
                                    tspan(class="sale-price-svg", y="60%") .95
                                else
                                    if locale == "fr"
                                        tspan(class="sale-copy", x="30%", y="40%") !{ __("homepage.sale_sticker_svg")}
                                    else
                                        tspan(class="sale-copy", x="35%", y="40%") !{ __("homepage.sale_sticker_svg")}
                                    tspan(class="sale-price-svg", x="25%", y="60%") $
                                    tspan(y="75%", class="sale-price-9") 9
                                    tspan(class="sale-price-svg", y="60%") .95
                            polygon.st1(points='78.8,1.7 84.2,9 90.8,2.6 95.1,10.8 102.6,5.4 105.5,14.2 113.7,10.1 115.3,19.1 124.1,16.4 \
                                          124.2,25.6 133.3,24.3 131.9,33.3 141.1,33.4 138.4,42.2 147.4,43.8 143.4,52 152.1,54.9 146.7,62.4 154.9,66.7 148.5,73.3 \
                                          155.8,78.8 148.5,84.2 154.9,90.8 146.7,95.1 152.1,102.6 143.4,105.5 147.4,113.7 138.4,115.3 141.1,124.1 131.9,124.2 \
                                          133.3,133.3 124.2,131.9 124.1,141.1 115.3,138.4 113.7,147.4 105.5,143.4 102.6,152.1 95.1,146.7 90.8,154.9 84.2,148.5 \
                                          78.8,155.8 73.3,148.5 66.7,154.9 62.4,146.7 54.9,152.1 52,143.4 43.8,147.4 42.2,138.4 33.4,141.1 33.3,131.9 24.3,133.3 \
                                          25.6,124.2 16.4,124.1 19.1,115.3 10.1,113.7 14.2,105.5 5.4,102.6 10.8,95.1 2.6,90.8 9,84.2 1.7,78.8 9,73.3 2.6,66.7 10.8,62.4 \
                                          5.4,54.9 14.2,52 10.1,43.8 19.1,42.2 16.4,33.4 25.6,33.3 24.3,24.3 33.3,25.6 33.4,16.4 42.2,19.1 43.8,10.1 52,14.2 54.9,5.4 \
                                          62.4,10.8 66.7,2.6 73.3,9 ')
```

Comment: what lang is this ??

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question, so we can see what is happening for ourselves.  If you make readers have to do work to see what's happening, you are much less likely to get help.

Comment: @Adam it is jade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel very silly. All I had to do was change the order of the 'points' and the 'text' divs so text was read afterwards and it solved my issue.

```
svg(version='1.1', xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', xmlns:a='http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/', x='0px', y='0px', width='100%', height='100%', viewbox='0 0 157.5 157.5', style='enable-background:new 0 0 157.5 157.5;', xml:space='preserve')
                            style(type='text/css').
                                .st1 {
                                    fill: #ff3a1e;
                                    stroke: #ff3a1e;
                                    stroke-width: 2;
                                    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                                }

                                .sale-copy {
                                    font-size: 20px;
                                    font-weight: 600;
                                    fill: #fff;
                                }

                                .sale-price-svg {
                                    font-size: 20px;
                                    font-weight: 600;
                                }

                                .sale-price-9 {
                                    font-size: 55px;
                                    font-weight: 700;
                                }
                            defs
                            polygon.st1(points='78.8,1.7 84.2,9 90.8,2.6 95.1,10.8 102.6,5.4 105.5,14.2 113.7,10.1 115.3,19.1 124.1,16.4 \
                                  124.2,25.6 133.3,24.3 131.9,33.3 141.1,33.4 138.4,42.2 147.4,43.8 143.4,52 152.1,54.9 146.7,62.4 154.9,66.7 148.5,73.3 \
                                  155.8,78.8 148.5,84.2 154.9,90.8 146.7,95.1 152.1,102.6 143.4,105.5 147.4,113.7 138.4,115.3 141.1,124.1 131.9,124.2 \
                                  133.3,133.3 124.2,131.9 124.1,141.1 115.3,138.4 113.7,147.4 105.5,143.4 102.6,152.1 95.1,146.7 90.8,154.9 84.2,148.5 \
                                  78.8,155.8 73.3,148.5 66.7,154.9 62.4,146.7 54.9,152.1 52,143.4 43.8,147.4 42.2,138.4 33.4,141.1 33.3,131.9 24.3,133.3 \
                                  25.6,124.2 16.4,124.1 19.1,115.3 10.1,113.7 14.2,105.5 5.4,102.6 10.8,95.1 2.6,90.8 9,84.2 1.7,78.8 9,73.3 2.6,66.7 10.8,62.4 \
                                  5.4,54.9 14.2,52 10.1,43.8 19.1,42.2 16.4,33.4 25.6,33.3 24.3,24.3 33.3,25.6 33.4,16.4 42.2,19.1 43.8,10.1 52,14.2 54.9,5.4 \
                                  62.4,10.8 66.7,2.6 73.3,9 ')
                            text(x="50%", y="50%", fill="#FFFFFF")
                                if (/^(en-gb|fr)$/.test(prefLocale))
                                    if locale == "fr"
                                        tspan(class="sale-copy", x="30%", y="40%") !{ __("homepage.sale_sticker_svg")}
                                    else
                                        tspan(class="sale-copy", x="35%", y="40%") !{ __("homepage.sale_sticker_svg")}
                                    tspan(class="sale-price-svg", x="25%", y="60%") £
                                    tspan(y="75%", class="sale-price-9") 9
                                    tspan(class="sale-price-svg", y="60%") .95
                                else
                                    if locale == "fr"
                                        tspan(class="sale-copy", x="30%", y="40%") !{ __("homepage.sale_sticker_svg")}
                                    else
                                        tspan(class="sale-copy", x="35%", y="40%") !{ __("homepage.sale_sticker_svg")}
                                    tspan(class="sale-price-svg", x="25%", y="60%") $
                                    tspan(y="75%", class="sale-price-9") 9
                                    tspan(class="sale-price-svg", y="60%") .95
```